# Android OpenGL matrix values

Tags: android, matrix, opengl-es

I am using android.opengl.Matrix for scaling, transformation and rotation for OpenGL2.0 2D graphics and that works all OK.

My problem is trying to read individual matrix values so I can use those values for other processing. In particular I need to be able to read the x and y transformation values.

I have searched online for ages and seen suggestions to use

```
float[] f = new float[9];
myMatrix.getValues(f);
```

but the code will not compile as due to 'Cannot resolve method for getValues(float[])'

Is there any way I can read an individual matrix values or the transformation values when using android.opengl.Matrix ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type has `myMatrix`? Afaik you can't instantiate a `android.opengl.Matrix` starting from API level 19.

Comment: `android.graphics.Matrix` has a `getValues` however `android.opengl.Matrix` does not and it only contains static members.